# Filter javascript array of objects to contain specific field

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object that looks like this:

```
[
   { "customer": "2222", "owners": { "1": "aaa", "2": "bbb" }, "title": "V1" },    
   { "customer": "1111", "owners": { "1": "aaa", "2": "bbb" }, "title": "V2" }
]
```

I want to filter the array to contain only the `owners` field.

```
[
    {"owners": { "1": "aaa", "2": "bbb" }},
    {"owners": { "1": "aaa", "2": "bbb" }}
]
```

I tried something like

```
const filterArr = (arr, obj) => taskArray.filter( task => Object.keys(task).some( key => obj[key]));
```

But it doesn't work because it is not really referring to the name of the key in the array.

Any help?

Comment: You want a `.map()` then. `taskArray.map( ({owners}) => ({owners}) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `filter`, you can just use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each object in the original array to another object having the structure you want:

```js
var arr = [
   { "customer": "2222", "owners": { "1": "aaa", "2": "bbb" }, "title": "V1" },    
   { "customer": "1111", "owners": { "1": "aaa", "2": "bbb" }, "title": "V2" }
]

var result = arr.map(obj => ({'owners' : obj['owners']}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Map function, you will get `undefined` if owners don't exist.

```js
var arr = [
   { "customer": "2222", "owners": { "1": "aaa", "2": "bbb" }, "title": "V1" },    
   { "customer": "1111", "owners": { "1": "aaa", "2": "bbb" }, "title": "V2" }
];

function pluckArray(array,key){
  var a = [],
     i={},i1 = -1, i2 = array.length,
      o ;

    while(++i1 < i2)
    {
        o = array[i1] ; // you have to use the bracket operator here
        if(o.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            i[key] = o[key];
            a.push(i);
        } ;
    }
return a;
}

console.log(pluckArray(arr, 'title' ));
```